# Assert.ReferenceEquals() Passes where Object.ReferenceEquals() returns 'false' in Visual Studio Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, equals, assertions

In attempting to create an initial, failing unit test in Visual Studio Professonal 2008's test capabilities, I can't seem to get `Assert.ReferenceEquals()` to correctly fail when an object instance is *not* equal to a null reference. Note that `object.ReferenceEquals()` is correctly returning `false` for this same comparison.

Here is my class code:

```
public static class Project
{
    public static object TheObject { get; set; }

    public static void Startup(object theObject)
    {
        // ToDo: Project.Startup(): Test.
        // ToDo: Project.Startup(): Implement.
    }
}
```

And then here are the key aspects of my test class:

```
[TestClass()]
public class ProjectTest
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void StartupTest()
    {
        object obj = "hello";
        Project.Startup(obj);    
        Assert.ReferenceEquals(obj, Project.TheObject); // Test Passes!?!
    }
}
```

Note that the `static void Startup(object)` method is empty, so the `static object TheObject` property is never set and remains `null`. So, clearly, `Assert.ReferenceEquals(obj, Project.TheObject)` should fail, but somehow this test passes.

Note that changing

`Assert.ReferenceEquals(obj, Project.TheObject)`

to

`Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(obj, Project.TheObject))`

causes this test to *correctly* fail.

This seems too simple, and yet I cannot see what's going wrong here. If someone can point out the error in my ways, I would be much obliged.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

**Update Answered by James Avery:**

Ah, an how silly I feel now. I *knew* it had to be something like this. Wow.

Sure enough, 'GoToDefinition' takes me to 'Object.ReferenceEquals()'. So typing "Assert.ReferenceEquals()" is really System.Object.ReferenceEquals(), which in my case was quietly returning 'false'. This, of course, has nothing to do with actually failing an assertion, so the test *passes*. Amazing.

Thanks James.

Comment: I just got hit with this same silly mistake.  It's such an easy trap to fall into.  It seems like the unit test classes could at least throw up a warning if no actual Assertions were called.  That would at least catch the very simple cases like your sample code above and the particular property check I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: "It seems like the unit test classes could at least throw up a warning if no actual Assertions were called." <-- That's a pretty interesting idea and not just to protect against this silly trap. I like it.

Comment: A better idea, though, would be for the Assert class to create a new static method called 'ReferenceEquals' that would shadow the 'Object.ReferenceEquals' method and then mark that method with the ObsoleteAttribute with an appropropriate error message. This way the user would be warned if they made this mistake.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The ReferenceEquals method you are calling is the static method available on all reference objects, it is not part of the testing framework. If you look it is returning a boolean value whereas a normal assertion would be void. This is definitely confusing, .AreSame() is the assertion you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, an how silly I feel now. I *knew* it had to be something like this. Wow. Sure enough, 'GoToDefinition' takes me to 'Object.ReferenceEquals()'.

So typing "Assert.ReferenceEquals()" is really Object.ReferenceEquals(), which in my case was quietly returning 'false' -- which, of course, has nothing to do with actually failing an assertion. So the test **passes**. Amazing. Thanks James.

Comment: I ran in to similar problem and NUnit throws an exception indicating not to use ReferenceEquals for assertions. I changed it to Assert.AreSame() as you suggested. They obviously overrode Assert.ReferenceEquals() to throw an exception, but why not override the function to do what we expect?